# i want to modify Redgate source control Git.xml file to include commit and push

Tags: sql-server

Below is an excerpt for the git.xml file in redgates source control

```
<element>
<key type="string">Commit</key>
<value version="1" type="GenericHookCommand">
<CommandLine>git commit -F "($MessageFile)" -o "($ScriptsFolder)\"</CommandLine>
<Verify>exitCode == 0</Verify>
</value>
</element>
```

i wish to modify it to include the push so when you do a commit in management studio it will also the push to git.

i have tried adding another command like

```
<CommandLine>git commit -F "($MessageFile)" -o "($ScriptsFolder)\"</CommandLine>
<commandline>git push</commandline>
```

and also tried

```
<CommandLine>git commit -F "($MessageFile)" -o "($ScriptsFolder)\" && git push</CommandLine>
```

but neither work, any idea on how to get the commit and push working

Comment: I have no idea about this product, but the `\"` (escaped quote) at the end of the original command looks really strange. Also, please don't cross-post ([Q on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13156145/i-want-to-modify-redgate-source-control-git-xml-file-to-include-commit-and-push)). You should post your question on only one site. If there's a better fit on the network, your question will be migrated.

Comment: Thanks Mat, the \" is OK(i believe) 
<CommandLine>git commit -F "($MessageFile)" -o "($ScriptsFolder)\"</CommandLine>

When the above is just used all works fine, but it only commits to my working directory
apologies on the multiple posts(newb)

Comment: What I'm saying is that it doesn't look normal and it would be an error if passed to a (unix) shell. Might work as you have it when it's the last thing on the line, might interfere if you try to do additional stuff after it. (But as I said, I have no clue about what the thing you're using is.)